# Not receiving response from HTTPS site using request module

Tags: python, python-2.7, https, python-requests

I am trying to access

```
https://www.exploit-db.com/remote
```

Using request module of python, however not getting the response from page. I want to visit all the links from above page.

```
mfun():
    response = requests.get('https://www.exploit-db.com/remote',verify=False)
    print(response.text)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('a[href^=/download/]')]

main():
    urls = myfun();
    for url in urls:
      response = requests.get(url)
      print(response.text)
```

I am getting response:

```
C:\Python27\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:791: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Comment: I get a [403 Forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) response, with the text in the HTML page `Sucuri WebSite Firewall -  CloudProxy - Access Denied`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site uses a firewall that looks for 'scripted' access. It can simply be defeated by setting a `User-Agent` header; the value `Mozilla/5.0` appears to be enough:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get('https://www.exploit-db.com/remote', headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Note that the resulting page has no URLs prefixed by `download`; only by `https://www.exploit-db.com/download`. Either adjust your `^=` prefix match, or use `*=download` instead.